# How to run command

Tags: bash, sudo

I need to run a `command` under `userx` using sudo that is normally not available in the `PATH`.  `Command` is available in bash under `userx` because of `HOME/.bashrc`.

Simply if I run in bash under `userx`

```
echo $PATH
/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/bin:/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

I get the right `PATH` and `command` is available.

But if I run with sudo:

```
sudo -u userx echo $PATH
/home/curuser/.pythonbrew/bin:/home/curuser/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

sudo -H -u userx echo $PATH
/home/curuser/.pythonbrew/bin:/home/curuser/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

sudo su python -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

sudo su python -c 'bash -c "echo $PATH"'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

PATH variable is not set using `userx`'s `.bashrc`.

How to run with sudo so that `PATH` will be normal `PATH` under `userx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run sudo with `-i` to have it start a new interactive shell (and load all the user configurations).

```
  -i [command]
               The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a
               login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If
               a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is
               specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the
               shell.  The security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal set of variables, similar to what is present
               when a user logs in.  The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the
               environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
```

Comment: Oops, I read this in man, but did not realize this is what I need. Also it's possible to use `su usrex -l -c "command"`

Comment: This needs the user's password instead of using `sudo`.